# Returning an audio file as response from AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway calling a Lambda function (with Proxy integration), which should return an audio file.

Let's say that I have my audio as 'bytes' object. How do I go about returning it, such that it can immediately be recognized and played by the browser (e.g. Firefox)?

Here's what I got, but, clearly, that doesn't really work.

```
sound: bytes

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'
    },
    'isBase64Encoded': True,
    'body': base64.b64encode(sound)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Solution for my case (**proxy integration**)

1. Base-64 encode the bytes object (e.g. `base64.b64encode(sound)` in Python) and put the result in `'body'` of your response dictionary.
2. Set `'isBase64Encoded'` to **true** in your response dictionary.
3. In API settings, set **Binary Media Types** to the appropriate media type and don't forget to set the client's Accept Header to the same value.

### Resources that helped me directly

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html

### Resources that might be useful

- https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html